# Работа с datetime в python, как убрать секунды из вывода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Я хочу, чтобы при выводе b - a не отображались секунды.
Я не понимаю в чем проблема, но сейчас они отображаются

```
In: s1 = 10:20, s2 = 19:00
Out: b-a = 8:40:00
```

Пример кода:

```
def timescript(s1 , s2):
    a = datetime.strptime(s1 , '%H:%M')
    b = datetime.strptime(s2 , '%H:%M')
    return b - a
```

Comment: ну так надо вывод форматировать в нужный формат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.strptime('10:20', '%H:%M')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('19:00', '%H:%M')
d = (b - a)  # 8:40:00

dd = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d), "%H:%M:%S")  # 1900-01-01 08:40:00
print(dd.strftime('%H:%M'))  # 8:40

print(f'{d.seconds // 3600}:{(d.seconds // 60) % 60}')  # 8:40

print(str(d).rsplit(':', 1)[0])  # 8:40
```

Answer (score 1):

Придётся исхитриться:

```
return ':'.join(str(b - a).split(':')[:2])
```

Comment: Да не нужно. Есть готовые инструменты для вывода даты-времени в нужном формате. Зачем придумывать велосипед?

Comment: Даты-времени есть, да. А вот с дельтой они вроде не работают.

Comment: Да, действительно.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Нужно сделать `datetime.strftime((b-a), '%H:%M'))`

Comment: Я пробовал сделать так:
from datetime import datetime

def timescript(s1 , s2):
    a = datetime.strptime(s1 , '%H:%M')
    b = datetime.strptime(s2 , '%H:%M')
    return datetime.strftime((b - a), '%H:%M')

print(timescript('10:20','19:00'))

Результат:
return datetime.strftime((b - a), '%H:%M')
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'datetime.timedelta'

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.time(hour=18, minute=42).strftime("%H:%M")
------
18:42
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это сработает с time, но не сработает с timedelta (по крайней мере, напрямую)